# React Native app works on simulator but stuck on a black screen when installed on device through TestsFlight

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm building a React Native which works fine when I run it on the simulator. However when I package it and put it on the Apple TestFlight, the app doesn't run on devices. All I see is a black screen.

I'm using the MongoDB Realm SDK if that may hold a clue to the problem. I'm fairly new to iOS development and only have the simulator to test the app.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this? Thank you!

Update: I tested the app on an iPod touch (iOS 14) and it works. So the problem seems occur only on iPhones.

Comment: Try run in a production mode in a  Xcode simulator and check if app is crashing

Comment: The app doesn't seem to crash when running in production mode but gets stuck on the login screen. I'm not sure how to debug this since it runs fine in development mode.

Answer (score 1):

This usually means that your app has crashed...Try using componentDidCatch and show an alert or something to get the error or try using sentry.io to catch crashes